# bazel is trying to use an old (and broken) version of protobuf?

Tags: protocol-buffers, bazel

Building a program with bazel on mingw, I get this error:

```
external/com_github_protocolbuffers_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/port_undef.inc:122:28: error: expected ')' at end of input
  122 | #pragma GCC diagnostic pop
      |                            ^
      |                            )
external/com_github_protocolbuffers_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/stubs/port.h:266:10: note: to match this '('
  266 |   return (((x & uint64_t{0xFFu)) << 56) |
```

That quoted line 266 is clearly completely wrong, which makes it easy to search for; it was fixed in the protobuf code in [this bug](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/8611), which was closed in May 2021 and probably released in 3.17.1.

This is coming from a version of protobuf that bazel has downloaded, presumably because it can't find the system protobuf library. So... why is it trying to use this old version of the library, and is there any way to make it stop?

Comment: Bazel uses or downloads the dependencies specified in the WORKSPACE file of the project, so best to start there.

Comment: In this case it will be something called `com_github_protocolbuffers_protobuf` in the WORKSPACE file

Comment: Huh. I didn't look there because I could have sworn it was empty, but apparently I put a referene to `rules_proto-4.0.0` in there and then forgot about it. But that's the version from the documentation in https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_proto, and I've checked the implementation and it's pulling in protobuf 3.20.0, in which the bug is fixed. So why isn't my system seeing it?

Comment: Looking at the version that bazel actually downloaded it appears to have gotten protobuf 3.17.0.

Comment: Ah, I misread the `rules_proto` version numbers. `rules-proto-4.0.0` actually points at the bad version. Any newer version looks fine. Unfortunately `rules-proto-4.0.0` is the one the documentation suggests you install!

Comment: ahh, yeah, might be good to file an issue with them to say that the version in the readme doesn't compile!